# Reloading app module doesn't take effect in erlang.mk based app

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I'm building an application using Erlang.mk with Cowboy and Sync. Recompiling works very well for most modules, except for `fragments_app` (fragments is the name of my project). I have a routing configuration there and when I change it (e.g. add new route) I'm getting a notification about module being recompiled:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 14-Apr-2017::19:56:59 ===
/app/src/fragments_app.erl:0: Recompiled.

=INFO REPORT==== 14-Apr-2017::19:56:59 ===
fragments_app: Reloaded! (Beam changed.)
```

but the change doesn't seem to be applied:

```
$ http :8080/fragments
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
content-length: 0
date: Fri, 14 Apr 2017 19:35:27 GMT
server: Cowboy
```

Also reloading module in console

```
c:l(fragments_app).
```

doesn't help, neither executing

```
sync:go().
```

If I stop the application and start it again, it works as expected.

At the same time updating handlers seem to take effect immediately - sync is picking it up and effect takes place without restarting the app.

Here is the source of `fragments_app.erl` after change:

```
-module(fragments_app).
-behaviour(application).

-export([start/2]).
-export([stop/1]).

start(_Type, _Args) ->
  Dispatch = cowboy_router:compile([
    { '_', [
      { "/fragments", fragments_http_handler, [] }
    ]}
  ]),
  { ok, _ } = cowboy:start_clear(fragments_http_listener, 100,
    [{ port, 8080 }],
    #{ env => #{ dispatch => Dispatch }}
  ),
  fragments_sup:start_link().

stop(_State) ->
  ok.
```

My Makefile:

```
PROJECT = fragments
PROJECT_DESCRIPTION = New project
PROJECT_VERSION = 0.1.0

DEPS = cowboy sync
dep_cowboy_commit = master

DEP_PLUGINS = cowboy

SP = 2

include erlang.mk
```

and relx.config:

```
{release, {fragments_release, "1"}, [fragments, sasl, runtime_tools]}.
{extended_start_script, true}.
{sys_config, "rel/sys.config"}.
{vm_args, "rel/vm.args"}.
{dev_mode, true}.
```

Why is this happening? Anything I can do to apply my changes without restarting the app?

Comment: See here for some (ongoing) discussion: https://twitter.com/lhoguin/status/852986294896664576

Answer (score 0):

In Erlang VM, It is possible to load 2 versions of any module code.

Then, each process will continue to execute its current version until it calls one of its module function, using a fully qualified call : module:function(Par...). It will use in this case the new code version. *It is the reason why it is useful to use the OTP behaviors which provide a code_change call back*.

The reason for this is that each process "can decide" when it will apply the change, and can also call a function to manage the version change (data adaptation for example).

The module `fragments_app` has an application behavior, it is called only to star and stop the application. If you want any change to be applied, you need to call it, and ensure it is executed, so you need to call the sequence

```
application:stop(fragments_app),
application:start(fragments_app),
...
```

Comment: Thank you @Pascal. These are definitely valuable insights. Unfortunately the code you have provided doesn't work for me and I'm not experienced enough with Erlang to apply your general remarks to my specific problem. I get `{error,{not_started,fragments_app}}`. I think it's specific to how `relx` works.

Comment: The message you get means that the application fragments_app is not started yet. I can't say if it is normal or not. I am not used to relx, but as your relx.config refers only to fragments, maybe you should test "application:stop(fragments)" and "application:start(fragments)"